# Retrieve EBIT from XBRL documents

Tags: xbrl, edgar

It appears that EBIT information is not very uniform across different XBRL documents.

Cross comparing data with other sources, such as Yahoo, I have seen some XBRL use the fact `us-gaap:OperatingIncomeLoss` to store it if using US-GAAP, or `ifrs-full:ProfitLossBeforeTax` if using IFRS.

However, sometimes it looks like they also use `us-gaap:IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeIncomeTaxesMinorityInterestAndIncomeLossFromEquityMethodInvestments` or `us-gaap:IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeIncomeTaxesExtraordinaryItemsNoncontrollingInterest`.

And sometimes many of those are actually filled with different values, so there is no way to know which one is correct.

Is there a more reliable way to retrieve EBIT data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of different concepts to mean the same thing is a general problem, which is beyond the XBRL specification and usually addressed by each reporting authority.

This has been investigated notably by Charles Hoffman, CPA who suggests using his [report frames](http://www.xbrlsite.com/2015/fro/us-gaap/html/ReportFrames/). Charlie explained how to build "standardized" US GAAP balance sheets, income statements and cash flow statements with a general mapping to the original reports, in order to compare companies in the EDGAR repository.